# class file for android.support.v4.widget.TintableCompoundButton not found

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, noclassdeffounderror, inflate-exception

I want to Create a CheckBox, My compile

```
sdk version is 23, 
Target version is 23, 
build tool version is 23.0.0,
```

in gradle I'hv added

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0', 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

both and in menifest given the app theme as `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` and no specific theme to Activity. when I run my code its throwing

```
InflateException line number #23 at xml file, problem while inflating kind of
```

Then I decided to convery a simple ChcekBox to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox` but on the xml file Preview its showing Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.widget.TintableCompoundButton
```

and if i try to run it it gives me class file for `android.support.v4.widget.TintableCompoundButton not found`.

So, Any one faced this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnv_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlv_header"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/confirmCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/personal_confirm_text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlv_next"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@color/crabfx_light_gray"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/crabfx_green" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/discloser"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/lbl_next"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/crabfx_green" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and below is the theme to Application tag in menifest
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: i updated question

Comment: did you find an answer to this ? :/